# Can I be DDoS-ed without any listening/responding IP address (UDP/TCP/ICMP)?

Tags: ddos

I'm asking this question because all if not most literature out there indicates that there is a listening or responding entity that is involved in an attack.

If I was behind a router that does not respond to ICMP or listen/NAT any services on UDP/TCP. Am I susceptible to a DDoS attack?

Comment: Basically any system connected to the internet is susceptible of been attack.

Comment: Do you have any data/techniques to prove it?

Comment: @MFT, What you're thinking here is that you've mitigated your risk of being used in an amplification DDoS (E.g. running an OpenDNS resolver or leaving LDAP ports open etc) which is for the most part true however, no one is really free from a Bandwidth based DDoS attack on their network.

Comment: We have a user here, @Satish, whose company gets hit with DDoS attacks. Perhaps he can explain the realities to you.

Comment: I welcome the explaination, thanks in advance.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

> If I was behind a router that does not respond to ICMP or listen/NAT any services on UDP/TCP. Am I susceptible to a DDoS attack?

Yes. At least on the bandwidth side, there could be more data coming in than the Internet downlink can handle. A severely congested interface loses massive amounts of packets and becomes unusable.

A faster Internet access makes a bandwidth-based attack harder, but *any* bandwidth can be exceeded with DDoS, especially when using amplification techniques.

With destination NAT on the router, you're *additionally* susceptible to have the NATed service or device overloaded. Depending on the firewall and the host configuration, a targeted (D)DOS attack may be much easier to achieve than a purely bandwidth-based attack.

Comment: Thanks Zac, how do you initiate a bandwidth attack, Layer 3 of course on a non-listening/responding device? In this case, it is a routed interface, a point-to-point link to the ISP?

Comment: You simply send lots of traffic to the target.  It doesn't matter if the target is listening or not: the traffic still consumes the bandwidth.

Comment: Thanks Ron, would it still consume the traffic if the router is configured to drop instead of resetting connections?

Comment: It wouldn't help a thing, you can only process it after it reaches you.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your knowledgeable answers. Was looking for scientific or at least explanations relating, ie packet flows, arp behaviour etc. Anyone has a citation to an RFC or something I can refer to?

Comment: I think you're over-thinking this.  If I send a thousand cars to a particular street address, it doesn't matter if there is a building there or not.  The roads will be congested with all the cars.  It's the same with network traffic:  even if your router is configured to drop all the traffic, the packets have already consumed the bandwidth by the time they get to your router.

Comment: @MFT Some attacks methods rely on something at the victim site responding, some do not.  Your router configuration will protect you against some but not all attacks.  You might care to review the different kinds of attack at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denial-of-service_attack

Comment: Further to @RonTrunk ... this is why some ISPs have mechanisms for customers to set up throttling/blocking/etc at the ISP.  Customer C says "I am blocking address X" and ISP will prevent ingress from X to C at the ISP perimeter.  Customer's lines not congested, ISP's lines saving bandwidth too.

Comment: @jonathanjo That's fine in the case where the attack comes from a single address.  but) DDOS attacks, by their very nature, come from hundreds or thousands of source addresses.  Blocking those is not so simple.

Comment: @RonTrunk of course absolutely agree with you.  Wasn't commenting on simplicity, merely that it really helps if you can block things getting onto your, typically few, wires.